# How to remove an old ip address from my connection script?

Tags: ip-address, sql

How can I remove the old ip address from my connection script?

Just now my site show:

> Error establishing a database connection.

I am using wordpress on mixedsoft.com (remote sql issues)

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the wp-config.php file. This contains the constants defined for your connection script.

You will find this file in the root folder of your WordPress installation.

Comment: That's correct, you need to enter the IP in wp-config instead of localhost as well as make sure your username and password are correct for the MySQL server. I would also make sure that if you need to enable remote myself you have set that for your IP.